# RPi 1 B+ boot failure on bullseye, buster works fine

Tags: hdmi, boot-issues, raspberry-pi-os-bullseye, pi-b+

I have an old Raspberry Pi Model B+ (B Plus) 512MB that has been going strong for years and I was trying to update it to bullseye. I started with a clean SD card and the RPi Imager. I can't seem to get HDMI working even with `hdmi_force_hotplug=1` and `hdmi_safe=1` in `config.txt`. When I do get it to boot I see errors in `udev`. Boots fine with an old SD card (`Stretch`) and with a fresh install of `Buster`. When it hangs it is partially booted, I can ping it but I can't SSH into it. I can't get HDMI working on the old `Stretch` image or `Buster` either so there may be something broken there.

I disabled HDMI in the V3D driver and board level.  This seems to help.  Is there anything else I could do to get HDMI working or clean up the errors in the log?

```
# Enable DRM VC4 V3D driver
dtoverlay=vc4-kms-v3d,nohdmi
max_framebuffers=2

dtparam=hdmi=off
```

This is the logs and dmesg

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ cat /etc/os-release
PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)"
NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="11"
VERSION="11 (bullseye)"
VERSION_CODENAME=bullseye
ID=raspbian
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianForums"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianBugs"
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ systemd-analyze
Startup finished in 7.647s (kernel) + 39.016s (userspace) = 46.663s
multi-user.target reached after 38.237s in userspace
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ journalctl -p 3 -xb
-- Journal begins at Wed 2022-09-21 19:23:41 CDT, ends at Fri 2023-02-03 15:15:11 CST. --
Feb 02 11:42:36 raspberrypi kernel: hwmon hwmon1: Failed to get throttled (-110)
Feb 02 11:42:38 raspberrypi kernel: raspberrypi-clk soc:firmware:clocks: Failed to change fw-clk-m2mc frequency: -110
Feb 03 15:14:33 raspberrypi systemd-udevd[124]: soc:gpu: Worker [129] processing SEQNUM=1002 killed
Feb 03 15:15:11 raspberrypi kernel: INFO: task kworker/0:1:14 blocked for more than 122 seconds.
Feb 03 15:15:11 raspberrypi kernel:       Tainted: G        WC        5.15.84+ #1613
Feb 03 15:15:11 raspberrypi kernel: "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
Feb 03 15:15:11 raspberrypi kernel: INFO: task systemd-udevd:129 blocked for more than 122 seconds.
Feb 03 15:15:11 raspberrypi kernel:       Tainted: G        WC        5.15.84+ #1613
Feb 03 15:15:11 raspberrypi kernel: "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ dmesg

[   45.462352] ------------[ cut here ]------------
[   45.462401] WARNING: CPU: 0 PID: 126 at drivers/firmware/raspberrypi.c:67 rpi_firmware_property_list+0x1dc/0x25c
[   45.462489] Firmware transaction timeout
[   45.462502] Modules linked in: vc4(+) sha256_generic libsha256 snd_soc_hdmi_codec cfg80211 cec rfkill 8021q garp stp llc drm_kms_helper snd_soc_core bcm2835_codec(C) bcm2835_v4l2(C) bcm2835_isp(C) v4l2_mem2mem bcm2835_mmal_vchiq(C) snd_compress videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_dma_contig videobuf2_memops snd_pcm_dmaengine videobuf2_v4l2 syscopyarea sysfillrect videobuf2_common raspberrypi_hwmon sysimgblt fb_sys_fops snd_bcm2835(C) snd_pcm videodev snd_timer snd vc_sm_cma(C) mc uio_pdrv_genirq uio fixed drm fuse drm_panel_orientation_quirks backlight ip_tables x_tables ipv6
[   45.463127] CPU: 0 PID: 126 Comm: systemd-udevd Tainted: G         C        5.15.84+ #1613
[   45.463161] Hardware name: BCM2835
[   45.463178] Backtrace:
[   45.463205] [<c08cc38c>] (dump_backtrace) from [<c08cc5d4>] (show_stack+0x20/0x24)
[   45.463291]  r7:00000043 r6:00000009 r5:c06faa0c r4:c0add43c
[   45.463309] [<c08cc5b4>] (show_stack) from [<c08cfb78>] (dump_stack_lvl+0x24/0x28)
[   45.463360] [<c08cfb54>] (dump_stack_lvl) from [<c08cfb90>] (dump_stack+0x14/0x1c)
[   45.463402]  r5:c06faa0c r4:c0b4867c
[   45.463418] [<c08cfb7c>] (dump_stack) from [<c0024988>] (__warn+0xe8/0x110)
[   45.463471] [<c00248a0>] (__warn) from [<c08ccb84>] (warn_slowpath_fmt+0x9c/0xd8)
[   45.463529]  r7:00000009 r6:c06faa0c r5:00000043 r4:c0b4867c
[   45.463545] [<c08ccaec>] (warn_slowpath_fmt) from [<c06faa0c>] (rpi_firmware_property_list+0x1dc/0x25c)
[   45.463617]  r9:00000000 r8:00000000 r7:0000000c r6:c11c90c0 r5:cbc02000 r4:00001000
[   45.463635] [<c06fa830>] (rpi_firmware_property_list) from [<c06faafc>] (rpi_firmware_property+0x70/0x118)
[   45.463694]  r10:c44bba6c r9:00030066 r8:0000000c r7:c11c90c0 r6:00000000 r5:00000000
[   45.463714]  r4:c44bba60
[   45.463732] [<c06faa8c>] (rpi_firmware_property) from [<bf298ea4>] (vc4_drm_bind+0x29c/0x2ec [vc4])
[   45.464524]  r10:c0d1ea64 r9:00000006 r8:c11c90c0 r7:00000000 r6:c11c7210 r5:bf2c2a6c
[   45.464547]  r4:c5325000 r3:00000000
[   45.464563] [<bf298c08>] (vc4_drm_bind [vc4]) from [<c05d15dc>] (try_to_bring_up_master+0x16c/0x1c8)
[   45.465278]  r9:00000006 r8:c3328420 r7:c44bb460 r6:c4522bb8 r5:c4522bb8 r4:c44bb3c0
[   45.465302] [<c05d1470>] (try_to_bring_up_master) from [<c05d1abc>] (component_master_add_with_match+0xc0/0x100)
[   45.465420]  r10:bf298890 r9:00000000 r8:c11c7210 r7:bf2c29f4 r6:c11c7210 r5:c0d1ea50
[   45.465444]  r4:c44bb460
[   45.465461] [<c05d19fc>] (component_master_add_with_match) from [<bf298f98>] (vc4_platform_drm_probe+0xa4/0xd8 [vc4])
[   45.466103]  r7:c0c2f028 r6:c11c7010 r5:bf2cf680 r4:bf2c3058
[   45.466123] [<bf298ef4>] (vc4_platform_drm_probe [vc4]) from [<c05dbee4>] (platform_probe+0x68/0xc8)
[   45.466737]  r10:c0c2f028 r9:bf2cf820 r8:00000020 r7:c11c7210 r6:bf2cf094 r5:00000000
[   45.466759]  r4:c11c7210
[   45.466774] [<c05dbe7c>] (platform_probe) from [<c05d9a10>] (really_probe+0x15c/0x328)
[   45.466839]  r7:c11c7210 r6:bf2cf094 r5:00000000 r4:c11c7210
[   45.466860] [<c05d98b4>] (really_probe) from [<c05d9c6c>] (__driver_probe_device+0x90/0xf4)
[   45.466916]  r7:c11c7210 r6:bf2cf094 r5:bf2cf094 r4:c11c7210
[   45.466933] [<c05d9bdc>] (__driver_probe_device) from [<c05d9d10>] (driver_probe_device+0x40/0xd8)
[   45.466984]  r5:c0ddbb64 r4:c0ddbb60
[   45.466999] [<c05d9cd0>] (driver_probe_device) from [<c05da124>] (__driver_attach+0x74/0x100)
[   45.467057]  r9:bf2cf820 r8:c5303514 r7:c0c2f028 r6:bf2cf094 r5:c11c7210 r4:00000000
[   45.467075] [<c05da0b0>] (__driver_attach) from [<c05d79b4>] (bus_for_each_dev+0x80/0xc4)
[   45.467129]  r7:c0c2f028 r6:c05da0b0 r5:bf2cf094 r4:c11c2630
[   45.467146] [<c05d7934>] (bus_for_each_dev) from [<c05d926c>] (driver_attach+0x28/0x30)
[   45.467198]  r7:00000000 r6:c53034e0 r5:c0d1ef00 r4:bf2cf094
[   45.467215] [<c05d9244>] (driver_attach) from [<c05d8bc4>] (bus_add_driver+0x18c/0x1f0)
[   45.467261] [<c05d8a38>] (bus_add_driver) from [<c05da7fc>] (driver_register+0x84/0x118)
[   45.467318]  r9:bf2cf820 r8:c5303ac8 r7:00000000 r6:c0c2f028 r5:bf2c3038 r4:bf2cf094
[   45.467335] [<c05da778>] (driver_register) from [<c05dbcd8>] (__platform_driver_register+0x28/0x30)
[   45.467386]  r5:bf2c3038 r4:00000000
[   45.467403] [<c05dbcb0>] (__platform_driver_register) from [<bf15303c>] (vc4_drm_register+0x3c/0x1000 [vc4])
[   45.468005] [<bf153000>] (vc4_drm_register [vc4]) from [<c000a054>] (do_one_initcall+0x4c/0x1cc)
[   45.468611]  r5:bf153000 r4:bf2cf820
[   45.468629] [<c000a008>] (do_one_initcall) from [<c009ffa8>] (do_init_module+0x50/0x208)
[   45.468691]  r8:c5303ac8 r7:00000002 r6:c53cc620 r5:00000002 r4:bf2cf820
[   45.468708] [<c009ff58>] (do_init_module) from [<c00a265c>] (load_module+0x237c/0x2788)
[   45.468757]  r6:c5303a80 r5:00000002 r4:c26f3f20
[   45.468774] [<c00a02e0>] (load_module) from [<c00a2be4>] (sys_init_module+0x17c/0x1ac)
[   45.468826]  r10:bf000000 r9:b6f91d00 r8:c0c2f028 r7:dc89fad0 r6:00000000 r5:b5b99ad8
[   45.468848]  r4:00000000
[   45.468864] [<c00a2a68>] (sys_init_module) from [<c00083cc>] (__sys_trace_return+0x0/0x14)
[   45.468906] Exception stack(0xc26f3fa8 to 0xc26f3ff0)
[   45.468938] 3fa0:                   b6f92a78 b5b3f008 b5b3f008 0005aad0 b6f91d00 00000000
[   45.468972] 3fc0: b6f92a78 b5b3f008 00020000 00000080 00758340 0057196b 005719dc 00758190
[   45.468998] 3fe0: b6fa3e10 be8246f0 b6f89c0c b6e378f0
[   45.469028]  r10:00000080 r9:c26f2000 r8:c00083e4 r7:00000080 r6:00020000 r5:b5b3f008
[   45.469048]  r4:b6f92a78
[   45.469064] ---[ end trace bbadc02dabba23d8 ]---
[   45.469114] vc4-drm soc:gpu: [drm] Couldn't stop firmware display driver: -110
[   45.469399] vc4-drm soc:gpu: bound 20400000.hvs (ops vc4_hvs_ops [vc4])
[   45.470542] vc4-drm soc:gpu: bound 20004000.txp (ops vc4_txp_ops [vc4])
[   45.471669] vc4-drm soc:gpu: bound 20206000.pixelvalve (ops vc4_crtc_ops [vc4])
[   45.688393] vc4-drm soc:gpu: bound 20207000.pixelvalve (ops vc4_crtc_ops [vc4])
[   45.689728] vc4-drm soc:gpu: bound 20807000.pixelvalve (ops vc4_crtc_ops [vc4])
[   45.690647] vc4-drm soc:gpu: bound 20c00000.v3d (ops vc4_v3d_ops [vc4])
[   45.798390] [drm] Initialized vc4 0.0.0 20140616 for soc:gpu on minor 0
[   45.798517] vc4-drm soc:gpu: [drm] Cannot find any crtc or sizes
[   46.962445] hwmon hwmon1: Failed to get throttled (-110)
[  243.687061] INFO: task kworker/0:2:51 blocked for more than 122 seconds.
[  243.687130]       Tainted: G        WC        5.15.84+ #1613
[  243.687153] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
[  243.687170] task:kworker/0:2     state:D stack:    0 pid:   51 ppid:     2 flags:0x00000000
[  243.687222] Workqueue: events get_values_poll [raspberrypi_hwmon]
[  243.687293] Backtrace:
[  243.687322] [<c08d44b0>] (__schedule) from [<c08d4e94>] (schedule+0x78/0x138)
[  243.687401]  r10:c0ca18a0 r9:ffffa548 r8:c13dbdcc r7:c0ca0720 r6:c0c2f028 r5:c18a0ea0
[  243.687424]  r4:ffffe000
[  243.687440] [<c08d4e1c>] (schedule) from [<c08d9f24>] (schedule_timeout+0x1a0/0x2bc)
[  243.687500]  r5:c0ca18a0 r4:00052388
[  243.687517] [<c08d9d84>] (schedule_timeout) from [<c08d5b08>] (wait_for_completion_timeout+0xb8/0x140)
[  243.687578]  r10:c0c2f028 r9:00000002 r8:c1190cf0 r7:ffffe000 r6:c0c2f028 r5:c1190cec
[  243.687600]  r4:00057e40
[  243.687617] [<c08d5a50>] (wait_for_completion_timeout) from [<c072a324>] (mbox_send_message+0xc8/0x148)
[  243.687675]  r9:00000000 r8:00000000 r7:c13dbe90 r6:00000007 r5:a0000013 r4:c1190ce0
[  243.687694] [<c072a25c>] (mbox_send_message) from [<c06fa908>] (rpi_firmware_property_list+0xd8/0x25c)
[  243.687766]  r9:00000000 r8:cbc0201c r7:00000010 r6:c11c90c0 r5:cbc02000 r4:00001000
[  243.687786] [<c06fa830>] (rpi_firmware_property_list) from [<c06faafc>] (rpi_firmware_property+0x70/0x118)
[  243.687844]  r10:c6ab77ec r9:00030046 r8:00000010 r7:c11c90c0 r6:c13dbef8 r5:00000004
[  243.687867]  r4:c6ab77e0
[  243.687883] [<c06faa8c>] (rpi_firmware_property) from [<bf38c0a4>] (get_values_poll+0x44/0x120 [raspberrypi_hwmon])
[  243.687951]  r10:c33e01b0 r9:dbf55405 r8:00000000 r7:dbf55400 r6:00000000 r5:c0c2f028
[  243.687975]  r4:c33e01ac r3:00000004
[  243.687992] [<bf38c060>] (get_values_poll [raspberrypi_hwmon]) from [<c003ef5c>] (process_one_work+0x20c/0x4dc)
[  243.688069]  r5:c189e780 r4:c33e01ac
[  243.688087] [<c003ed50>] (process_one_work) from [<c003f260>] (worker_thread+0x34/0x598)
[  243.688149]  r10:c0c38494 r9:00000008 r8:c0ca0720 r7:c0c384a8 r6:c189e798 r5:c0c38494
[  243.688170]  r4:c189e780
[  243.688186] [<c003f22c>] (worker_thread) from [<c0046ea0>] (kthread+0x144/0x16c)
[  243.688251]  r10:c13f8b9c r9:c1123e90 r8:c13da000 r7:c189e780 r6:c003f22c r5:c13cc1a0
[  243.688273]  r4:c13f8b80 r3:00000000
[  243.688289] [<c0046d5c>] (kthread) from [<c00082f4>] (ret_from_fork+0x14/0x20)
[  243.688330] Exception stack(0xc13dbfb0 to 0xc13dbff8)
[  243.688362] bfa0:                                     00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[  243.688392] bfc0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[  243.688420] bfe0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000013 00000000
[  243.688450]  r10:00000000 r9:00000000 r8:00000000 r7:00000000 r6:00000000 r5:c0046d5c
[  243.688474]  r4:c13cc1a0 r3:60000093
[
```

Comment: Probably not of much help, but: https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v5.8/admin-guide/tainted-kernels.html

Comment: First thought is some of the changes they've made to the default install in RPi?? If you have another RPi, try booting it from the SD card that's failing.

Comment: I suspect there is a HW issue and the display driver changed from what was in buster to vc4-kms-v3d.  The only dispaly driver did not cause the system to hang in such a way that the ssh service did not start.  The new display driver does.